# SSIS pipe delimiter issue for CRLF csv file

Tags: ssis-2012

I am Facing an below pipe delimiter issue in SSIS.

```
CRLF Pipe delimited text file:  
-----------------------------
Col1|Col2  |Col3
1   |A/C No|2015 
2   |A|C No|2016
```

Because of embedded pipe within pipes SSIS failing to read the data.

Comment: You might let the file source delimit it the way it wants to and then use a Derived Column to knit the separate columns back together.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news: once you have a file with this problem, there is NO standard way for ANY software program to correctly parse the file.

Good news: if you can control (or affect) the way the file is generated to begin with, you would usually address this problem by including what is called a "Text Delimiter" (for example, having field values surrounded by double quotes) in addition to the Field Delimiter (pipe).  The Text Delimiter will help because a program (like SSIS) can tell the field values apart from the delimiters, even if the values contain the Field Delimiter (e.g. pipes).

If you can't control how the file is generated, the best you can usually do is GUESS, which is problematic for obvious reasons.